# Android ART: "Failed to find Dex offset for PC offset ..."

Tags: android, art-runtime

I have recently stumbled upon this very strange bug that causes a crash while developing an app.
Here is a logcat screenshot:
[image: LOGCAT]

And here is the code of the function in which supposedly it crashes:

```
private static long Round(double d)
{
    return Math.round(d * 1000.0);
}
```

What can be done here? Should I report this problem?

EDIT: It might be relevant to an infinite recursion problem I had, because the problem seems to be gone now...

Comment: Does it work with Dalvik?

Comment: I also got this due to a StackOverflowError. On Dalvik it shows the stacktrace properly.